# ASP.Net Core serilog not created in Linux VM

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

I developed my app in windows platform but I published in linux azure vm.
my problem is serilog is created on my development system but in linux vm this serilog not created.
this is my appsettings.Production.json file. 
**What should I do to create this logs file?**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Will be loaded by Pipline"
  },
  "SendGrid": {
    "ApiKey": "Will loaded by pipeline",
    "FromEmail": "will loaded by pipeline"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "FilePath": "/var/log/Roulette/myapp.log",
    "Template": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
    "RollingInterval": "Day"
  },
  "PaypalConfig": {     
    "ClientId": "will be populated",
    "ClientSecret":"will be populated" 
  }
}
``
```

Comment: On the linux instance the filenames and paths are case-sensitive - does the `/var/log/Roulette/` path exist? If it doesn't, does the application have permission to create it?

Comment: Yes the path exists. How to check that permission?

Comment: I gave 755 permission to  myapp.web.dll but not changed.